# haskell "invalid type signature error"

Tags: haskell

I defined the function `NewLine`

```
NewLine :: String -> String
NewLine (x:xs)=if (x=='\n') then xs else NewLine xs
```

It gives me an invalid type signature error, but I don't see why.

Answer (score 30):

Functions can't begin with uppercase letters in Haskell. Uppercase letters denote a data constructor.